# cypher return nodes located in the same place

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is a simple query, but i don't know which cypher operation or java collection would be useful to get the expected result.

So, again working with users assigned to a specific Taxi, where each user has a Grid destination (drop off).

First i returned the users assigned to a specific Taxi and same dropOff time:

```
MATCH (g:Grid)<-[d:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[rt:ASSIGNED]->(t:Taxi {name: 'Taxi1813'})
WHERE d.time = '04:38' 
RETURN u.name, g.name as LocationGrid

u.name           LocationGrid
UserTestSame     Grid1239
UserTestNew      Grid919
User177          Grid1239
```

I would like to add a condition to return the users located in the same Grid. The result set is not fixed; i may have *n* number f users.

Is there an easy way to do that, or should i use a collection in java to compare each Grid.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate Cypher's built-in aggregate functions, such as `collect`:

```
MATCH (g:Grid)<-[d:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[rt:ASSIGNED]->(t:Taxi {name: 'Taxi1813'})
WHERE d.time = '04:38' 
RETURN g.name as LocationGrid, collect (u.name) as users

LocationGrid    users
Grid1239        [UserTestSame, User177]
Grid919         [UserTestNew]
```

Your query assumes that users assigned to the same taxi have the same drop off time? Seems confusing to me, but I might be missing something.

BTW, I don't think storing and matching the drop off time as a string is going to be very suitable for following reasons:

- querying will be inefficient as you'll probably need to match both a date and a time string property
- it doesn't allow for matching drop off times which are close

I'd recommend modelling the drop off time as a time tree. See following links for reference:

- [How to represent days in timeline tree for Neo4j/graphDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498626/how-to-represent-days-in-timeline-tree-for-neo4j-graphdb)
- [Neo4j: Cypher – Creating a time tree down to the day](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/)
- [performance of time filters in neo4j where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057353/performance-of-time-filters-in-neo4j-where)
- [Importing Forests into Neo4j](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/04/importing-forests-into-neo4j/)

Comment: it works.  Thank you for your suggestions. I'm going to do some changes

Answer (score 1):

//just use the answer above me
Also Neo4j has an option to use **collect** so the results come back in a list.

Match(n)-[]->(r)
return n, collect (r) as collection

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-collect

I think you should change your  date time. Not in a string but more like yyyyMMddhhmmss so you can compare. Or any other way.

It would also be faster not to store it as a string.

Comment: Thank you @Mvde for your suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome also you could think about structuring your data an otherway.  
Because now your user is between grid and taxi so there is no way of telling wich user used wich taxi. If you have multiple dropoffs connecting to the same user. Or is your user just a node. It would spend some time drawing some graphs

Comment: A User is just a node, and it has a single dropOff location (Grid) and a single assigned Taxi. So far, i just made the relation which users are assigned to a Taxi (:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->(:Taxi), but not the otherway around.